# How to make "SharePoint:FormField" required?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, required, formfield

I'm making a SharePoint 2010 new/edit item custom form.
I have a title field:

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" ID="fieldFileLeafRef" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="FileLeafRef" />
```

How to make this field required?

Answer (score 0):

FormField is a Control that would render the UI for any of the Field you assign it to , it doesn't not represent any field Statically. In your code you are refering or pointing the FormField to point to **FieldName="FileLeafRef"**, so in this case you will need to set the Field as Required in your Content Type or List so that FormField will render a validator or do validations.

Comment: Kusek, thanks for your answer, I understand this FormField logic and I already have FileLeafRef set to be required in Content Type I'm using: <FieldRef ID="{8553196d-ec8d-4564-9861-3dbe931050c8}" Name="FileLeafRef" Required="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" /> but in form it's still not required.

Comment: Well FileLeafRef is not that is something Editable, It is the Url of the File in Document library or Item in List so you will not be able to make it Editable. Only way you can get the value or set it is to upload the file

Comment: Ok, FileLeafRef usage is other topic, because I can't make even simple Text type field to be required if I render it this way (SharePoint:FormField).